# LogonUser, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK

Tags: winapi, impersonation

Can anyone provide a clear explanation of the difference between LOGON32__LOGON_INTERACTIVE and LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK when used with LogonUser?

The MS documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx).

But I'm not clear what should be used. The scenario is similar to a telnet server that Windows users (local to the server, and domain users) are logging into - I want to impersonate the user in the thread. They may want to delete files or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at http://www.bitvise.com/wug-logontype for a thorough discussion of the issue and a recommendation:

> We recommend that users who require
>   terminal shell access use the
>   'interactive' logon type.